# How to stop Scanner changing bytes when inputing data from file in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using the Scanner utility in Java to input data from a file like so:

```
        File file = new File("mazes.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);  
        scan.useDelimiter("__________\n");  
        String record = scan.next();
```

but it is changing certain bytes to other bytes. For example, where the record string should be a byte with hexadecimal value `80`, Scanner seems to turn this into a byte with a hex value of `ac`. How can I input records from the file without any switching of the bytes like this?

Comment: You'll have to convince us that something is wrong. Post input, output, and expected output please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of the constructor:

> Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying
>   platform's default charset.

If your file has another encoding, you must use (e.g.):

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(file,"UTF-8");
```

or

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(file,"ISO8859-1");
```

etc.

Comment: whhhooooo, specifying that the file is ISO has worked, thanks so much, this is truly helpful  :)